# Django-Storages not being installed properly

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, python-django-storages

I'm working on deploying my first django app to an EC2 server. I'm serving my static files from an S3 server, so I'm using the django-storages app.

I installed it using `sudo pip install django-storages` on the EC2 server. However, I keep getting the error "no module found" when I try to import it. Yet, when I run `pip freeze` django-storages shows up as installed.

I followed the exact same procedure on my development machine and everything works perfectly. Any ideas?

I should also mention that the EC2 server is running the bitnami ubunutu 64 bit django stack.

Comment: What is the import command you're running?

Comment: I just enter the python terminal and run import storages.  The error also presents itself when I run syncdb.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using virtualenv I find you don't need to add in sudo. So just try doing a pip install django-storages?